# Searching for Number of Term Appearances in Mathematica

Tags: search, text, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to search across a large array of textual files in Mathematica 8 (12k+). So far, I've been able to plot the sheer numbers of times that a word appears (i.e. the word "love" appears 5,000 times across those 12k files). However, I'm running into difficulty determining the number of files in which "love" appears once - which might only be in 1,000 files, with it repeating several times in others.

I'm finding the documentation WRT FindList, streams, RecordSeparators, etc. a bit murky. Is there a way to set it up so it finds an incidence of a term once in a file and then moves onto the next?

Example of filelist:

{"89001.txt", "89002.txt", "89003.txt", "89004.txt", "89005.txt", "89006.txt", "89007.txt", "89008.txt", "89009.txt", "89010.txt", "89011.txt", "89012.txt", "89013.txt", "89014.txt", "89015.txt", "89016.txt", "89017.txt", "89018.txt", "89019.txt", "89020.txt", "89021.txt", "89022.txt", "89023.txt", "89024.txt"}

The following returns all of the lines with love across every file. Is there a way to return only the first incidence of love in each file before moving onto the next one?

```
FindList[filelist, "love"]
```

Thanks so much. This is my first post and I'm largely learning Mathematica through peer/supervisory help, online tutorials, and the documentation.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote helpful answers (when you get to 15 reputation), and if one answers your question, mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, rcollyer (always good to know community standards). It might take me a bit of time to fully resolve this Q as I implement the suggestions, but I would certainly upvote these if I had the rep.

Comment: Check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for a thorough explanation of the standards.

Comment: @ian A small change in your userid could be nice: avoid starting it with "i" as the capitalization mutates it into "I", which is impossible to distinguish from lowercase "L", and you will miss comments

Comment: @belisarius Great call, I've changed my username.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516469/searching-for-number-of-term-appearances-in-mathematica/7516569#7516569), you also seem to be asking for a list of files where the word only occurs once.  To do that, I'd continue to run `FindList` across all the files

```
res =FindList[filelist, "love"]
```

Then, reduce the results to single lines only, via

```
lines = Select[ res, Length[#]==1& ]
```

But, this doesn't eliminate the cases where there is more than one occurrence in a single line. To do that, you could use [`StringCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringCount.html) and only accept instances where it is 1, as follows

```
Select[ lines, StringCount[ #, RegularExpression[ "\\blove\\b" ] ] == 1& ]
```

The [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegularExpression.html) specifies that "love" must be a distinct word using the word boundary marker (`\\b`), so that words like "lovely" won't be included.

**Edit**: It appears that `FindList` when passed a list of files returns a flattened list, so you can't determine which item goes with which file.  For instance, if you have 3 files, and they contain the word "love", 0, 1, and 2 times, respectively, you'd get a list that looked like

```
{, love, love, love }
```

which is clearly not useful.  To overcome this, you'll have to process each file individually, and that is best done via `Map` ([`/@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html)), as follows

```
res = FindList[#, "love"]& /@ filelist
```

and the rest of the above code works as expected.

But, if you want to associate the results with a file name, you have to change it a little.

```
res = {#, FindList[#, "love"]}& /@ filelist
lines = Select[res, 
         Length[ #[[2]] ] ==1 &&  (* <-- Note the use of [[2]] *)
         StringCount[ #[[2]], RegularExpression[ "\\blove\\b" ] ] == 1&
        ]
```

which returns a list of the form

```
{ {filename, { "string with love in it" }, 
  {filename, { "string with love in it" }, ...}
```

To extract the file names, you simply type `lines[[All, 1]]`.

Note, in order to `Select` on the properties you wanted, I used `Part` ([`[[ ]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html)) to specify the second element in each datum, and the same goes for extracting the file names.

Comment: Thanks very much as well, this is helpful. I'll keep tinkering with it, and this helps open up some further ideas about working on data by analyzing the line level.

Comment: @Ian, belisarius noted a flaw in `FindList`, so I've added a work around, in addition to fixing a small error in my prior code.

Comment: Great, I am trying it right now - thanks so much for your generous help!

Comment: It seems to be working. The Map(/@) command above was the pivotal addition! This is all great stuff that I'll keep as reference as I go forward in textual processing.

Answer (score 4):

Help > Documentation Center > FindList item 4:

"FindList[files,text,n]
includes only the first n lines found."

So you could set n to 1.

Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: @Daniel It does not identify in which files the word is apperaing only once, does it?

Comment: @belisarius, worse than that, it appears to flatten the list entirely so you can't determine which is which.

Comment: @belisarius No, does not give the files. But that data is not in the request, just a length.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, perhaps I am misunderstanding the question

Comment: @belisarius I think it (the question) is evolving. Which is fine-- a bit of refinement as responses provide insights is often a good thing.